# Plotly Bubble Maps hover event coorditants

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I need to create custom tooltip, i created additional div which i show/hide on "plotly_hover" and "plotly_unhover". That works but the issue is that **hover event coordinates often do not coincide with the point itself on the map** since **the event usually occurs before the cursor touches the point itself**

[image]
[image]

I would like to have my own tooltip works like a standard one.

I used **event.offsetY** and **event.offsetX** but they give me exact exact cursor coordinates which i don't need.

I did not find the coordinates in the event object that would relate to the standard tooltip

[image]

There is some object **points[0].bbox** with four coordinates but I still don't understand what they mean

Comment: You can try to reduce the [hoverdistance](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-hoverdistance) to increase the precision of the event trigger. You could also customize the hover box by defining your own [hovertemplate](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/scattergeo/#scattergeo-hovertemplate) (or you need another separate tooltip ?). The bbox data corresponds to the clientXY coordinates of the box that contains the area being hovered.

Comment: Thanks EricLavault! Yes, i need a custom tooltip because i have to style it using css which is not possible for standart tooltip (as i know). Hoverdistance option works for me very well, i set it equal to 1 instead of default value 20. Also i will try to play with bbox data, maybe I will be able to show my tooltip in the same way as the default does

Comment: I left hoverdistance by default but used bbox data like this:
tooltip.style.top = data.points[0].bbox.y0  + 'px'
tooltip.style.left = data.points[0].bbox.x1 + 'px'
With this the custom tooltip appears always top right of a circle which is under hover